# Is there a way to get a Google OAuth2 token with email and password using Go?

Tags: go, firebase-realtime-database, oauth-2.0, access-token

I am trying to avoid using a service account for my Go application and I need a way to authenticate with my database. I found a way to [authenticate with a service account json](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/oauth2/google) but I am hoping to find a way with just an email and password for an existing Firebase user. How would I do this in Go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The is no way to sign in to Firebase Authentication with the provided Go Admin SDK. What you **can*** do is the call the REST API for Firebase Authentication to [sign in](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-sign-in-email-password), and then use that to [authenticate with the REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth) for the Realtime Database.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. Is there a way to sign in with firebase authentication and then use that token to authenticate with the admin SDK by using option.WithCredentials() or something?

Comment: You can't sign in to the Admin SDK, it runs with administrative privileges. And I don't immediately see a way to tell the [Go client](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/firestore) that the Admin SDK wraps to pass along a specific ID token.

Comment: [From the NewApp function](https://pkg.go.dev/firebase.google.com/go#NewApp) it looks like you can auth through an oauth2.TokenSource. 

"If the client options contain a valid credential (a service account file, a refresh token file or an oauth2.TokenSource) the App will be authenticated using that credential."

Is this something that I could use?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. Firebase Authentication's ID tokens are JWTs, which can't be passed to that call as far as I know.

Comment: [Apparently this is what can be passed in](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/oauth2@v0.0.0-20211005180243-6b3c2da341f1#Token) . Just wanted to double check to see if this would be the right token type.

Comment: I don't think so, as those are access and refresh tokens. But give it a try and let me know, as I'd love to learn that I'm wrong here. :)

Comment: I gave it a shot and it does not seem to work unless I am configuring it wrong, I think you are right in your explanation!